# aws glue crawler creates multiple tables, how to combine them to one?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

If I have 5 csv files in aws s3 storage, where one has schema slightly different from other 4, and I have a crawler that makes a schema for me, and "Create a single schema for each S3 path" is marked in crawler settings, how many tables will I get as a result, 5 or just 2, or 1? 
I mean, in this case, will crawler make a separate table for each file, even there are 2 groups of schemas, or it is smart enough to group schemas and output just 2 tables? Or even 1? 
An example [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-grouping-policy) suggests that there should be 1 output table for all 5 files, but I don't see this behavior, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you tried enabling "Create a single schema for each S3 path." in your crawler and see if working. Better to create a new crawler by deleting existing crawler and tables created

Comment: Thanks bdcloud, yes I tried new crawler, enable/disable "Create a single schema for each S3 path" in different combinations, and every time I got just many tables as a result of crawler run.